# Unable to login to Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my pc which is way old along with Windows XP. After installation I got a message "Run ubuntu in low graphics" I clicked yes and then I was asked for user name and password. But I keep getting the same screen over and over.

To summarize my ubuntu installation is hung at the login screen.

Comment: When you went through installation you should have been prompted for a user id and password to use. That's what you should enter here. If you don't remember the password please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password. You could also reinstall. This sometimes happens when, either when initially prompted, or at login, the caps lock key is down and the person typing doesn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Try bringing your computer up in Recovery Mode, drop to the console and reset your password with the "passwd" command, then boot up normally.   If you're running on an old system without too many resources you might try installing the Lubuntu variant, as it works better (faster) on systems like this.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me that your user account doesnt have administrator access, known as ROOT. 
To do this you need to enable ROOT and that way you can run certain devices and installations.

With my first experience I installed ubuntu to a virtual pc rather than dual boot and played that way. I could surf the net on it and things were less risky, now with my knowledge and understanding i feel as if I can play and understand how to make this opperating system much more functional.

Comment: You do *not* need to enable logging on as root, to make a user an administrator. Enabling root logins is neither necessary nor recommended in Ubuntu. See [this page in the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) for details (including about how to properly perform administrative tasks).